# Creating a simple data output file in Java

Tags: java, dataoutputstream

I am trying to write a simple data output file.  When I execute the code I get a "No file exist" as the output and no data.txt file is created in the dir.

What am I missing?  The odd thing is that it was working fine the other night, but when I loaded it up today to test it out again, this happened.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DataStreams {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\data.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                out.write(i);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("No file exist");
        }
    }
}
```

The data file should be a simple display of numbers 1 through 9.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Well, after deleting and reentering the directory address of where I wanted to write the file to - it worked.  I didn't answer my question yet in case anyone has anything to add as to why it might not have worked initially.  I apologize for not troubleshooting this idea before posting question.

Comment: try printing the exception which is being thrown by using   ioe.printStackTrace() in the catch block. Then you can confirm what is the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows platforms, `C:\` is a restricted path by default. Previously the application may have been run as `administrator` allowing access.

Solution: Use a different location

```
DataOutputStream out = 
    new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/data.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file named data.txt in c: .You must have deleted the file. Creating that file manually will work

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the exception itself:

```
System.out.println("No file exist");
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
```

Perhaps you have not the necessary rights, to access `C:\` with your program.

Answer (score 0):

1. To write data into a file, you should first create it, or, check if it exists.Otherwise, an IOException will be raised.
2. Writing in C:\ is denied by default, so in your case even if you created the file you will get an IOException with an Access denied message.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       File output = new File("data.txt");
       if(!output.exists()) output.createNewFile();
       try {
           DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               out.write(i);
           }
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
           System.out.println("No file exist");
       }
   }
   ```